# Blender 2.78a crashes when rendering a sequence (GPU)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I'm rendering (2.78a + Cycles) a rather complex architectural animation on 3xGPU and just randomly, after any number of frames rendered, Blender crashes. So it does start rendering, goes on for a few frames, and then crashes.

I did what people have suggested in the past (full screen and lock interface), it worked for a while, but not anymore.

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

My system is pretty good: i7 6850, 64gb ram, 3x GTX1080 8gb ram. 
Scene Peak memory at rendertime: 3.4gb
(CPU rendering is not a feasible option.)

Comment: try to identify what is happening on those frames where it crashes, maybe there is a new element or some kind of simulation? Use a program like msi afterburner to check memory and GPU usage as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
There isn't anything changing during the animation. it's just really slow camera movements...
I'll check with MSI afterburner.

Comment: I've been using CPU-Z and GPU-Z to check status on devices but nothing abnormal to notice..